# How to enable enable messaging queue (MSMQ) on a ftp server

Tags: ftp, queue, msmq

I have a website hosted on a ftp server, I dont have access to that server except ftp credentials and a plex panel support. I want to use MSMQ to use queues so basically on local I have enabled MSMQ through windows features. But when I publish site on ftp server, it gave error: 
Message Queuing has not been installed on this computer

So please help me to sort out this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only got FTP-credentials you are stuck with what the system administrator has set up for you. There is no chance you can get MSMQ running there without the sysadmin doing the installation work.